# AWS Amplify GraphQL subscriptions fail with "Cannot return null for non-nullable type: 'AWSDateTime' within parent 'Todo' (/onCreateChat/createdAt)"

Tags: amazon-web-services, flutter, aws-lambda, graphql, aws-appsync

I'm trying to add todo from lambda function in AWS.
I created flutter project, added api (Graphql basic Todo sample), added function (enabled mutations).
Lambda is working and effectively adding entry to TODO list. Unfortunately, subscription started in flutter returns error:

```
Cannot return null for non-nullable type: 'AWSDateTime' within parent 'Chat' (/onCreateChat/createdAt)
```

I see this problem got solved in [Github](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-cli/issues/5542#issuecomment-731758272) where aleksvidak states.

> I had the similar problem and what I realised is that mutation which in fact triggers the subscription has to have the same response fields as the ones specified for the subscription response. This way it works for me.

This seems to solve many people's problem. Unfortunately, I don't understand what it means for basic TODO sample code.

Mutation:

```
type Mutation {
    createTodo(input: CreateTodoInput!, condition: ModelTodoConditionInput): Todo
...
```

Subscription:

```
type Subscription {
onCreateTodo(filter: ModelSubscriptionTodoFilterInput): Todo
    @aws_subscribe(mutations: ["createTodo"])
...
```

Isn't this code aligned with what Aleksvidak said? Mutation has (Todo) the same response type as Subscription (Todo), right?

Answer (score 0):

For my case it was missing `updatedAt` within Query that I perform inside Lambda function.

```
const query = /* GraphQL */ `
  mutation CREATE_TODO($input: CreateTodoInput!) {
    createTodo(input: $input) {
      id
      name
      updatedAt // <-- this was missing
    }
  }
`;
```